# How to make two labels consecutively? Second label correctly show new line?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, label

How to make two labels consecutively, so that the second end of the label at the screen moved the remainder of the text on a new line?

Example. First label - "I got it. Take me to the"
Second label - "Home Screen"

[image]

Comment: Do you want your `Label`s to look like the image or is the image showing what it currently looks like and you want it to look differently?

Comment: Can you show us the code? I don't know xamarin or how those strings are making it to the label, but for a single string you can input your environment's "new line" character using `Environment.NewLine`, such as like this: `"I got it. Take me to the" + Environment.NewLine + "Home Screen"`.

Comment: First. look like the image

Comment: If you'll be wrapped in stacklayout (orientation-horisontal), with a decrease in the width of the screen word "Screen" by word  fall "Home"

Answer (score 1):

Like @Quantic said you can simply add a new line to the text like:

```
Label.Text = "I got it. Take me to the" + Environment.NewLine + "Home Screen";
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
Label.Text = "I got it. Take me to the\nHome Screen";
```

Or use a `StackLayout`:

```
StackLayout layout = new StackLayout {
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    Children    = {
        new Label { Text = "I got it. Take me to the" },
        new Label { Text = "Home Screen" },
    }
}
```

All that being said, you might not want to do that since different screens will have different widths so you need to take that into account. Different devices can also change the text size in your app so that would also effect the size.

*Edit: If you want the tail end of the `Label` to truncate the text, then you would set the `LineBreakMode` of the `Label` like so:

```
Label.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation
```

Sometimes this does not work depending on the type of layout that your `Label` is contained in, so if it does not work, please let me know what kind of layout you are storing the `Label` in.

So if you have the `Label` in a `StackLayout` the truncation may not work right on Android. Try putting the `Label` in a `Grid` instead. See [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68266/tail-truncation-in-stack-layout-on-android) post for others who ran into this.

Comment: not what I want. Property Line Break mode, delete the word "Screen"  down by word "Hello"

Comment: @IgorStrekha So you want the word 'Screen' to not show up if it is going to go to a new line? Kind of like the title in [this](https://justmarkup.com/log/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/long-word-ellipses.png) image?

Comment: I do not want to the first and second label Tail Trunkation. I want when the screen width (say iPhone 5) will be small, the word "Scream" and go down to the top of the screen

Comment: @IgorStrekha I apologize, not sure what you are wanting. Could you create an image showing how you want it to look?

Comment: I want to make it so as in the my first picture

Comment: @IgorStrekha I understand now. Please post the code showing the type of layout that your `Label` is contained in.

Comment: i added answer. Please look

Comment: "Which is the same as doing: `Label.Text = "I got it. Take me to the\nHome Screen"`;" -- not true, on Windows `Environment.NewLine` is `\r\n`. Notepad for example will not make a new line for just `\n`.

Comment: @Quantic Right but in Xamarin, they are treated the same.

Comment: @IgorStrekha Nice to see you got it working! Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to have 2 Labels next to each other with Wrapping working like in your sample, that require non-rectangular bounding boxes and Xamarin.Forms (or any other UIKit I know) does not supports it.

But you can use a single `Label` with multiple Spans:

```cs
var formattedString = new FormattedString ();
formattedString.Spans.Add (new Span { BackgroundColor = Color.Red, ForegroundColor = Color.Olive, Text = "I got it. Take me to the " });
formattedString.Spans.Add (new Span { BackgroundColor = Color.Black, ForegroundColor = Color.White, Text = "Home Screen.", FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Bold });

var label = new Label {
    FormattedText = formattedString
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid Padding="0, 10, -10, 10" RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenHomePageCommand}"/>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <controls:ExtendedLabel x:Name="SimpleLabel"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    FontFamily="OpenSans-Semibold"
                                    FontSize="16.4"
                                    InputTransparent="True"
                                    Text="I got it. Take me to the "
                                    TextColor="{StaticResource Onahau}"
                                    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />

            <controls:ExtendedLabel x:Name="UnderlineLabel"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    FontFamily="OpenSans-Semibold"
                                    FontSize="16.4"
                                    InputTransparent="True"
                                    IsUnderline="True"
                                    Text="Home Screen"
                                    TextColor="{StaticResource Onahau}"
                                    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
        </Grid>
```

Comment: This my Hack. I want take width "SimpleLabel". And add  Margin to "UnderlineLabel". ))) But in code behind  not work.

var width = SimpleLabel.Width;
UnderlineLabel.Margin = new Thicknes (width, 0, 0, 0)